# Setting sender email address for survey collector via the SurveyMonkey API

Tags: api, surveymonkey

This is the top option available to non-API users when they are editing a survey collector, so someone at SurveyMonkey must have recognized that it is important.  However, the API documentation does not mention that capability. Is it actually available but not documented?

Comment: we're looking into it, I'll get back to you

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by adding the following in the JSON body in the POST request:

```
"sender_email":"email@address.com"
```

This is not mentioned in the Knowledge Base as far as I can tell. Working on the Platinum package, so not sure if this will work for other paid subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that option should be there. It will be available to add as an option when creating/updating a collector of type `email` soon.

See the collector docs https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-collectors or watch the docs on github (https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs) to be notified of when the change has been made.